# Recovery of deleted data in resetting Ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery, 17.04, reset

I have reset my Ubuntu 17.04 recently by using application Resetter 
 http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/reset-ubuntu-desktop-default-settings but I don't know it leads to delete all files and stuff present in my laptop. Those files are really important for me.
Is there any way to recover that data?
That data is very important for me. If it is possible please help me out. 
I have also tried to recover file using **Test Disk**
by seeing this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnNefxLydV8.
By that only some folders recovered but all folders are empty.

Please help me!

Comment: Reading the article, it seems that the data should not have been deleted. Please post the output of `ls /home`.

Comment: @AndroidDev the *text* of the article says that... but the captured dialog appears to say `Human users accounts will also be removed` - make of that what you will...

Comment: @steeldriver Right, but deleting an account doesn't necessarily remove the home folder... does it?

Comment: @AndroidDev due to article i have reset my laptop if i have any idea about it can delete my data than why i use it, I have searched some files of that data but i didn't get any result.

Comment: @PiyushMittal, the omgubuntu article you read is really outdated because it's based on its beta version wile there's a newer stable version. The auto reset option that you've used clearly stated that it will completely remove your home directory. Also the stable version of resetter has way more feature than the one you read at omg ubuntu. You most likely didn't read the warning message before you clicked the ok button. You should've read: https://github.com/gaining/resetter instead

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, the files were deleted, you can try to recover them: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

I would recommend `scalpel` or `foremost`.

IMPORTANT: don't install new software or don't download new files before restoring your data.